# React Native - Text not updating with array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, native

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {styles, styleBox} from './components/styles';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([
    {key: 'borderTopLeftRadius', display: 'Top Left', value: 0},
    {key: 'borderTopRightRadius', display: 'Top Right', value: 0},
    {key: 'borderTopStartRadius', display: 'Top Start', value: 0},
    {key: 'borderTopEndRadius', display: 'Top End', value: 0},
    {key: 'borderBottomLeftRadius', display: 'Bottom Left', value: 0},
    {key: 'borderBottomRightRadius', display: 'Bottom Right', value: 0},
    {key: 'borderBottomStartRadius', display: 'Bottom Start', value: 0},
    {key: 'borderBottomEndRadius', display: 'Bottom End', value: 0}
  ]);      

  const valueChangedHandler = (val, item) => {
    var index = values.findIndex(value => value.key == item.key);
    var newValues = values;
    newValues[index].value = val;
    setValues(newValues);
    console.log(values[index].value);
  }  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>      
      <View style={styleBox(values)}>        
      </View>      

      <FlatList
        data={values}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <View style={styles.Item}>
            <Text style={styles.Label}>{item.display}</Text>      
            <Slider 
              style={styles.slider}
              value={item.value} 
              onValueChange={value => valueChangedHandler(value, item)}
              minimumValue={0}
              maximumValue={100}
              step={1}
            />
            <Text>{item.value}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Adjusting the sliders changes the value in the array correctly. (you can confirm through the console.log).

But the text after the slider doesn't change, even though the value itself changed.

Is it because of the Flatlist or do i need to trigger a rerender?

Comment: setValues([...newValues]); - Try this

Comment: Along with the comment from @UKS you can pass the index that you get from flatlist and remove the findIndex

Comment: @UKS it worked, thank you.

Comment: OK i will put that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach,

```
 const valueChangedHandler = (val, item) => {
    var index = values.findIndex(value => value.key == item.key);
    var newValues = values;
    newValues[index].value = val;

    //spread operator will return new array with updated values
    setValues([...newValues]); 
  }
```